Recent guide for using Amazon SES with CiviCRM and Wordpress
I am navigating my way through setting up civiCRM for the first time, without access to a paid expert or IT specialist. So I need a "dummy's" guide to using a value-for-money (ie cheap) smtp relay service sa Amazon SES. I expect small email volumes - less than 100 per month.
I have only found documentation that is many years old and very confusing. Is there a recent step-bystep guide for a non-developer developer?
